# Assistance with "Not a member of an array"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

Alright, so I'm trying to learn Visual Basic.  I took a class 15 years ago and haven't done anything since.  I found a tutorial on Youtube and am following along.  I entered the following code as copied from the video:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()

    Dim myText As String = "You can get what you want out of life " & _
        "if you help enough other people get what they want."

    Dim charArray() As Char = myText.ToCharArray()

    Array.Reverse(charArray)

    For Each myChar As Char In charArray
        Console.Write(myChar)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

When I run it, I get an error on Array.Reverse saying **'Reverse' is not a member of an 'Array.'**

I saved what I had and opened a new project.  I entered the exact same text in and it worked.  I then copied and pasted the code into Notepad, re-opened my original file, completely deleted everything that was in it, then pasted the code from Notepad into Visual Studio - and I got the error again.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.  When I open the project, I get the options for  the Target Framework as .NET 5.0 and .NET Core 3.1.  So far as I can tell the only difference is choosing one vs the other, but I'm curious if anyone else knows if there's a different reason I might be having this problem.

Comment: I can't make a Core or Framework project which doesn't recognize Array.Reverse, so sorry, can't reproduce.

Comment: If you go to definition of Array, does it bring you to the metadata file `"Assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0...`?

Comment: When I try to go to the definition I get a popup that says "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret."

Comment: are there any methods in auto-complete after you type `Array.`?

Comment: Main is the only method in the auto-complete.

Comment: It auto-completes to Array.Main()?

Comment: You can consider sharing your original file on github which will help others reproduce your problem.

Comment: @XingyuZhao I've never used github, so not sure I'm doing what you're asking, but I uploaded 2 zip files here.  One works and the other does not.  https://github.com/Chris3460/VBFail

Comment: @ChristopherCass In the version that doesn't work the root namespace is Array it is conflicting with Array the object. The full path for an array object would be System.Array. Most project would import System by default so it commonly gets dropped as a prefix.

Comment: That makes sense!  Thank you @RyanRoos!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if you get the same error, taken from dotnetperals.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim a() As Integer = {1, 4, 6, 10}

        For Each v As Integer In a
            Console.WriteLine(v)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()

        ' Reverse entire array.
        Array.Reverse(a)

        For Each v As Integer In a
            Console.WriteLine(v)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

If this works, try to slowly change it (one thing at a time) to looking and functioning like your code. If not, you likely have a framework issue, you may want to check your configuration and setup, not sure what the problem might be.

Comment: Also, consider this. Since arrays are mutable: Arrays.Reverse(a) is functionally equivalent to a = a.reverse()

Correct me if i am wrong, (i dont use VB any more) but instance variables of type array do have a .reverse function, right?